# How can I tell if a kdb server is busy?

Tags: kdb

Is there a command to know if the kdb server is busy running a query? Even better, knowing what is the percentage completion of the query being run?

So far I've been looking at the top screen on linux to know which server to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not directly. The reason is due to the single threaded nature of a KDB process. In practice, this is easily worked around by adding some basic logging to your server. So whenever a query comes in just log to a file the time the query came in and when the result was returned to the user.

Take a look at the [.z.pg](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zpg-get) and the [.z.ps](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zps-set) functions which are called to handle synchronous or asynchronous requests, respectively. By default they are just set to "value", which means evaluate the string and return the result. Just replace this with your own function to log events to a file or a log server.

Answer (score -1):

Besides above solution, a more simple way is: keep checking the port.

Normally all queries will be running against port, and kdb server can launched multiple ports for different purpose.

Details:
Use below code to query again port, if the port is busy, null res will return. And you can further kill the port and restart it or whatever the requirement is.

*The code will send out 1 to the port and calculate.*

```
.server.testQuery:{[inPort]
  res:@[{hopen(x;3000)};`$":",":" sv string `,inPort;0N];
  if[not null res;hclose res];
  :res  
  };
```

Comment: A 'kdb server', i.e. a kdb process serving something, can only launch itself on one tcp port, not multiple. It of course can switch ports, but will only ever be serving on one.

Comment: Can U pls carefully check, that u need to launch multiple ports to support multiple as I said, e.g. 5000,5001,5003

Comment: Hi kevin - sorry but I'm not understanding your comment? But to confirm, if that's what you asking, a single q process can only serve data on one port

Comment: @SeanO'Hagan sure, it is common sense, but u can launch multiple process on SAME server to support multiple port